# how to share xsl code with stack overflow developer

Tags: xml, xslt

I am facing one issue while parsing my XML with an XSLT.
I want to ask a question in this forum.
But I am not able to share code.

No share button is present in [this W3schoools example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog).

Could you please suggest any editor where I write my demo and share my code.

I want to get the minimum price value.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="abc.xsl"?>

<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    </catalog>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/title">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Try searching for "xsl fiddle" https://duckduckgo.com/?q=xsl+fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An editor which is capable of processing your requests was already suggested in the comments.

If you like to retrieve the minimum of the `<price>` elements, you can use the following XSLT snippet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">        
    <xsl:template match="/catalog">
        <xsl:for-each select="cd"> 
            <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:text>Minimum price: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="price/text()" />
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which outputs the minimum value of all `<price>` tag values:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
Minimum price: 9.90
```

Comment: could you pls tell me what is the use of xsl:function ?

Comment: @user944513: [`<xsl:function>`](https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xslt/xslt-referenz/function/) is an XSLT-2.0 tag. You neither specified your question as an _XSLT-2.0 question_ nor is this relevant in answering your question. So why do you ask?

Comment: it ok ..i will search

Comment: @user944513: for what?

Comment: You may check [these SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xsl%3Afunction).